# Проблема с наследованием C++, среда Borland Builder 6.0

Tags: c++builder, c++

Есть такая проблема: имеется иерархия классов. В производных появляются новые методы. Есть массив указателей на базовый класс. Когда я создаю экземпляр производного класса и обращаюсь к нему через указатель базового, он пытается найти метод в базовом классе, который не существует.
Люди добрые, помогите, пожалуйста. Я пытался делать понижающее преобразование типа указателя с помощью `dynamic_cast`:

> `MO[0] = dynamic_cast<hero*>(MO[0]);`

Указатель вроде как меняет тип, но компилятор всё равно орёт

> "[C++ Error] Main.cpp(230): E2316 'Move' is not a member of 'map_object'".

Вот важная часть кода:

```
class map_object {
    int x,y, index;
  public:
    virtual void Draw()=0;
    void set_x(int _x);
    void set_y(int _y);
    int get_x();
    int get_y()y;
    void set_index();
    int get_index();
    map_object(int _x, int _y);
};

map_object *MO[100];

class moving_object: public map_object {
  public:
    virtual void Move(int _d);
    moving_object(int _x, int _y):map_object(_x, _y);
};

class creature: public moving_object {
    int health;
    void Death();
  public:
    void cure(int _health);
    void damage(int _damage);
    int get_health();
    creature(int _x, int _y, int _health):moving_object(_x, _y);
};

class mage: public creature {
    int mana;
  public:
    void mana_fill(int _mana);
    void mana_reduce(int _mana);
    int get_mana();
    mage(int _x, int _y, int _health, int _mana):creature(_x, _y, _health);
};

class hero: public mage {
  public:
    void Draw();
    hero(int _x, int _y, int _health, int _mana):mage(_x, _y, _health, _mana);
};

void __fastcall TfrmMain::FormKeyPress(TObject *Sender, char &Key) {
  switch (Key) {
    case 'w': {MO[0]->Move(0); break;}
    case 'd': {MO[0]->Move(1); break;}
    case 's': {MO[0]->Move(2); break;}
    case 'a': {MO[0]->Move(3); break;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Упс... Прошу прощения, когда набирал свой вопрос, он вышел весь в кучу, править тэгом <br>, вроде нормально выглядело в предпросмотре... А как вопрос опубликовался - все <br> почему-то вылезли О_о

Comment: @UnnamedPlayer, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора. Добавлять при этом теги `<br>` для перевода строк не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, учту.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте посмотреть на ваш код глазами компилятора. Вы объявили `MO` как массив указателей на объекты класса `map_object`, в котором метода `Move` нет. Вы присвоили его элементам значения через `dynamic_cast` к `hero` - наследнику `map_object`. Чего вы этим добились? А ничего. `MO` как был массивом указателей на `map_object`, так им и остался. Компилятору, в общем-то, всё равно, каких наследников `map_object`'а вы присваиваете `MO`, при обращении по этому указателю он всегда будет видеть только те поля и методы, которые объявлены в `map_object`. Если вы хотите вызывать методы наследников по указателю на их предка, необходимо привести указатель на предка к указателю на наследника. Именно здесь и нужно`*` использовать понижающее преобразование:

```
dynamic_cast<hero*>(MO[0])->Move(0);
```

`*` На самом деле не нужно. Если ваша иерархия классов подразумевает принудительные понижающие преобразования, то скорее всего это плохая иерархия. В вашей иерархии теряется весь смысл наследования - вынесение общего для нескольких классов функционала в базовый класс и уменьшение свяности (coupling) вашего приложения. К тому же есть ненулевая вероятность, что однажды вы сделаете понижающее преобразование объекта из другой ветки иерархии, что приведёт к вылету программы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение, но как тогда формировать иерархию? Всегда считал, что так максимально логично - есть самый базовый класс, от него наследуются остальные, постепенно обрастая методами и полями, формируя результирующие классы...

Comment: И ещё один вопрос - если всё же пользоваться данной иерархией, неужели нужно при каждом вызове метода делать dynamic_cast<hero*>(MO[0])->Move(0);? Можно ли один раз преобразовать тип указателя и вызывать метод обычным способом?

Comment: @UnnamedPlayer, Сама по себе ваша иерархия не так уж и плоха, проблема в том, как вы её используете. Насколько я понял, в методе `TfrmMain::FormKeyPress` вы обрабатываете только объекты-наследники `moving_object`. Так почему бы не хранить все ссылки на `moving_object` в отдельном массиве указателей на `moving_object`? Этим вы избавитесь от необходимости кастовать объекты для их перемещеия. К тому же, пропадёт вероятность кастануть объект, который не является наследником `moving_object`.

Comment: Если же хранить дополнительные ссылки на объекты `moving_object` не вариант, то попробуйте переписать `TfrmMain::FormKeyPress` так:

    moving_object* obj = dynamic_cast<moving_object*> MO[0];
    if (obj) {
        obj->Move(0);
    }

Comment: Так ведь проще, когда один массив универсальных указателей - мы ведь не только двигаем их - мы ещё отрисовываем, узнаём координаты и т.д. Или так не делается? О_о

Comment: @UnnamedPlayer, тогда почему у вас метод `Move()` не объявлен в классе `map_object`? Тем более что координаты объекта вы там храните. Вы можете в `map_object` оставить пустую реализацию этого метода или сделать его чисто виртуальным, а в подклассах (в частности, в `moving_object`) реализовать логику перемещения. Вы вообще планировали наследовать от `map_object` что-то, кроме `moving_object`?